# How to fetch build packages from other apt repositories in snapcraft

Tags: snap

I'm trying to build a snap that depends on gtk3d, the packages for which are only available in the Debian archive:

https://packages.debian.org/sid/libgtkd-3-dev

Is it possible to get `build-packages` to fetch packages from additional apt repositories than archive.ubuntu.com? Or is there another alternative to get snapcraft to fetch the packages from Debian?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this now by writing a very simple custom plugin (based on the 'nil' plugin).  Just put a sources.list file (containing the repos you want to install from) in your project's top-level directory, and put the following code in parts/plugins/your_plugin.py

```
import snapcraft
import os

class YourPlugin(snapcraft.BasePlugin):
    @classmethod
    def schema(cls):
        return {
            '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#',
            'type': 'object',
            'additionalProperties': False,
            'properties': {},
        }

    def enable_cross_compilation(self):
        pass

    @property
    def PLUGIN_STAGE_SOURCES(self):
        return open('sources.list', 'r').read()
```

After that, you may need to worry about gpg keys for the sources.  You can just add those to your system's apt keys.

```
$sudo apt-key add <file with repo's gpg key>
```

Depending on which repos you are trying to use in your snap, you may need to specify some special options for apt.  You can do this with a custom apt.conf file.  My apt.conf looks like this.

```
Acquire::ForceHash "sha1";
Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order { "bz2", "gz"; };
Acquire::Languages { "none"; };
```

You can make snapcraft use this file when it calls apt internally by setting an ENV variable.

```
$export APT_CONFIG=<path to custom apt.conf file>
```

Finally, edit your snapcraft.yaml to use your new plugin.

```
parts:
  custom-part:
    plugin: your_plugin
    stage-packages:
      - <package from custom repo>
```

Now, you can run "snapcraft snap", and it should install packages from the repositories listed in your custom sources.list file instead of the system's.

Comment: does this work with ppa's as well then?

Comment: Yes.  But you'll need to copy the PPA's gpg key to a file and install it with apt-key.  You can get a PPA's gpg key by clicking to expand ''Technical details about this PPA" on the PPA's landing page.  From there, follow the link under "Signing key:", and following the "keyId" link.  It will display the gpg for the PPA.  Copy that key to a file, and add it it to apt with apt-key.

Comment: So, I misread the question.  This is how you can get stage packages *not* build packages.  Sorry about that.

Comment: However, using binaries from ppa's as stage packages, couldn't one just start snapping effectively everything that's distributed as a .deb through a ppa?

Comment: You can always use the stage dir for build though.  That's what the cmake plugin does.

https://github.com/snapcore/snapcraft/blob/master/snapcraft/plugins/cmake.py

Comment: @AndrewKeech, you could try to just install the debs, but doing so may not work well with dependency resolution.

Comment: It's worth noting that, if you have multiple sources listed, the example plugin above will only read the first line of your sources.list. You could change PLUGIN_STAGE_SOURCES to return `"".join(open('sources.list', 'r').readlines())` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, there currently isn't a way to do this unless you build your snap on a Debian system, in which case, it will fetch the packages from the Debian repos.

Universal distribution support is coming, just not yet.